# How to copy sources from one branch to another in SVN?

Tags: svn

I need to copy the source from a branch `myproduct1/mymodule1/tags/AA.BB.CC.DD` to `myproduct1/mymodule1/branches/DefectXXX`.

To do this, I ran following SVN command and got the `svn: E200007: Cannot mix repository and working copy sources` message.

```
C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn cp -m 'Defect XXX' http://myserver/svn/myproduct1/mymodule1/tags/AA.BB.CC.DD http://myserver/svn/myproduct1/mymodule1/branches/DefectXXX
```

How can copy the code from one branch to another on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the quotes were the cause of the problem.

This one works:

```
C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin>svn cp -m "Defect XXX" http://myserver/svn/myproduct1/mymodule1/tags/AA.BB.CC.DD http://myserver/svn/myproduct1/mymodule1/branches/DefectXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a space in the source or destination urls, put double quotes (") around the urls.